# Experience manager default Tag

Tags: experience-manager

Where can I change xpm default tag  to something else?

There is an option to change this on the parameter schema for the CT level xpm block, but I would like to change this at a single place and to have it affect all items that use xpm blocks (on both PT and CT level)

Note: I have tried setting in the parameter schema for CT level xpm block from span to something else in the default field, but when I render pages again (and I have no values set in the templates) I still get span...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parameter Schemas don't really have a default setting, but what you can consider is to create a Compound Template Building Block (like the Default Finish Actions) and add your XPM TBB in there and set the values you like in there.

Then instead of using the XPM TBB directly on your template, you use the Compound TBB and have the correct settings. You will still need to change all of your current templates, but for the future ones it will be set correctly. To make it easier on yourself, you could consider including the Default Finish Action in that Compound TBB, and name it Default Component Finish Actions (and you could create a Default Page Finish Actions the same way).

Comment: Hi Bart,
Tnx. I thought that there was maybe a setting on the system level (in configuration files or somewhere) where I could set new tag. But if there isn't (and <span> is coming from the Tridion.SiteEdit.Templating.EnableInlineEditingUI) then there is no way to avoid changing all my existing templates :)

Comment: The `<span>` is a built in default of the TBB indeed, so other than replacing that TBB with your own, you have no other option than to change all your templates indeed, but if you do it as I suggested, the in the future it will be less work.

Comment: A [non-delivery Custom Renderer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14655972/395495) lets us change all output without changing TBBs. I haven't seen many examples of them and even [Nuno Linhares recommends "global" TBBs over this extension point](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14673228/395495) (which might be forgotten).

Comment: @BartKoopman, it seems that changing configuration through parameter schema on the tbb level changes tags for fields, but not the tag for component presentation. It still remains (<span><!-- Start Component Presentation: {"ComponentID" :....). Is it possible to change this tag as well ?

Comment: @user3760419 there are two parameters: `Default Component Presentation HTML Tag` and `Default Field HTML Tag`, they are documented in the Template Builder through a URL on your CMS: `http://your.cms.url/TemplateBuilder/TemplateParameterDescriptions/EnableInlineEditingUI.html`, if you have set both to something different then `span` and you still get `<span>` tags, then I would guess that those spans are not generated by the TBB but are generated some other way (maybe even hardcoded somewhere).